# Any difference in collision chance between md5(stringa + stringb ...) and md5(stringa) + md5(stringb)?

Tags: hash, md5

I have a small data set with many fields, I want to checksum each row for quick comparison. There is no chance of malicious behaviour and it is not a big deal if there is a collision, but to reduce the probability I am wondering if I should md5 every column separately and add them together or add every column and md5 them and if there is a significant difference in collision chance between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"md5(a+b)" encodes order of a and b, while "md5(a)+md5(b)" doesn't. Thus the first form is a better way to calculate a combined hash value.